# How to extract module and phase from this transfer function?

Tags: signal-processing

I have this transfer function:
$$H(x)= \frac{1}{x+i(1+x)}$$
How can I extract module and phase and represent them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the module and phase of $1/z$ are the reciprocal of the module of $z$ and the negative of the phase of $z$, respectively. In case you don't know how to determine the module and phase of $x+\mathrm i(1+x)$, you might want to look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form).

Comment: Thank you. I forgot those properties that helped me solve the problem.